# JAXB creates extra xml elements during marshal

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I am using xjc from the java SDK to create my JAXB classes from the following xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="customer" type="customer"/>

    <xs:complexType name="customer">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="customerinfo" type="information"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="information">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:element name="infos" type="informations"/>
                <xs:element name="addressline" type="address"/>
                <xs:element name="string" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="informations">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="infos" type="informations"/>
                <xs:element name="addressline" type="address"/>
                <xs:element name="string" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="address"/>

</xs:schema>
```

As you can see it has some recursion in it with the "infos" element.
When i create my classes with xjc and make an instance of these classes as follows:

```
ObjectFactory objFact = new ObjectFactory();
    Customer customer = objFact.createCustomer();

    Information infoRoot = objFact.createInformation();
    Information infoInside = objFact.createInformation();
    Information infoInside2 = objFact.createInformation();
    Informations infos = objFact.createInformations();
    Address addressInside = objFact.createAddress();
    infos.getInfosOrAddresslineOrString().add(infoInside);
    infos.getInfosOrAddresslineOrString().add(addressInside);
    infos.getInfosOrAddresslineOrString().add("bla");
    Informations infosInside = objFact.createInformations();
    infosInside.getInfosOrAddresslineOrString().add(infoInside2);
    infoInside.setInfos(infosInside);
    infoRoot.setInfos(infos);

    customer.setCustomerinfo(infoRoot);

    JAXBElement<Customer> jaxbCustomer = objFact.createCustomer(customer);

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(jaxbCustomer, System.out);
```

The output is not as i would expect it to be:

```
<customer>
<customerinfo>
    <infos>
        <addressline xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="information">
            <infos>
                <addressline xsi:type="information"/>
            </infos>
        </addressline>
        <addressline/>
        <string>bla</string>
    </infos>
</customerinfo>
</customer>
```

As you can see there is an extra  element around the infos object that was never instantiated in the code.
Why is this element added to the marhsalled xml?